# Tag Manager - How can I track an outbound URL change when the button does not have an HREF?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Currently, when I click on a button - I have a redirect to an external link after a few seconds (while backend account creation occurs). The config file has the redirect URL - but my button href does not. How do I track this on tag manager?

Comment: There is no way to help you unless you include the HTML code for the button.

Answer (score 0):

You track it either by asking the front-end devs to push a DL event before redirection, or you just track the click on the button. For this, you create an any click trigger and add a condition for Click Element to match the CSS selector that would select your button.

If you need help with the selector, add your button's HTML and some around it to your question.